# multi-site ssl certificate

Tags: ssl, sni

We have a complete white-label application where clients have pointed domain to our IP address. When request comes in, we check $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] and serve up application based on $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].

Is it possible to use a multi-site SSL cert for all of our clients?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done in one of three ways:

1. SNI with a unique certificate per domain (as noted in the techrepublic link)
2. Wildcard certificate
3. Single certificate, with a lot of subjectAltName entries

The downside of (1) is that it only works with certain browsers.

The downside of (2) is that you probably can't get a wildcard certificate from a trusted CA (and even if you do, *.com doesn't match www.foo.com).

The downside of (3) is that, every time your company gets a new client, you need a new certificate (with the new subjectAltName).

Personally, I'd go with (1).

Comment: as for number 1, could I use same SSL certificate for multiple domains? Or would the SSL just apply to the IP address hosting those domains?

Comment: The advantage of (1) is that you can use regular one-domain-each certificates.  If you are hosting 163 different domains, you will have 163 different certificates.  The SNI magic ensures that someone going to foo.com gets the foo certificate, and someone going to bar.com gets the bar certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you'll want to make sure that you use a wildcard SSL certificate, but you should be good to go.